# Ruby trouble with arrays and sorting

Tags: arrays, ruby, sorting, integer

How can I count the amount of integers before that input and after.

```
user_array = user_input.chars.to_a

user_array.map {|item| item.to_i}
num = gets.to_i

arrange_array = user_array.push(num).join(",")
#need to give number before, and number after input
```

Comment: What trouble you are experience? What's your question?

Comment: You can get your first array by doing something like `array = gets.split.map(&:to_i)` then perhaps use `select` to select the elements you require.

Comment: The existing answers, including the one you've accepted, use the code you provided in **this** revision of your question. Please don't destroy the contents of your question. If you have a new question, you need to post it as a **new question**. If you're hitting the rate-limit on asking questions, you'll have to wait. Please do not substantially alter the content of this question again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
puts "Please enter some numbers:"
user_input = gets.chomp

puts "Please enter another number:"
num = gets.to_i

user_input.split('')
          .map(&:to_i)                # convert them to integers
          .partition { |n| n < num }  # split / partition by cond
          .map(&:sort)                # sort results
#⇒ [[0, 1, 2], [4, 5]]
```

The core of this solution is [`Enumerable#partition`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Enumerable.html#method-i-partition) method, that splits the array by the condition provided.

Answer (score 1):

```
#ENTER ARRAY OF NUMBERS
puts "Please enter some numbers:  "
user_input = gets.chomp

user_array = user_input.chars.to_a

user_array.map! {|item| item.to_i}
# important to ad the ! to the map method

#ENTER NUMBER
puts "Please enter another number:   "
num = gets.to_i

user_array << num
user_array.sort!
amount_before = user_array.index(num)
amount_after = user_array.count - user_array.index(num) - 1

puts "There are #{amount_before} integers before #{num}, and #{amount_after} integers after #{num}"
```